# How to plot $y(x)=4e^{\frac{-118300}{x}}$ in $[3000,25000]$ in python

Tags: python

I am new at python. I found this code for plotting $e^x$ in $[-2,2]$:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# 100 linearly spaced numbers
x = np.linspace(-2,2,100)

# the function, which is y = e^x here
y = np.exp(x)

# setting the axes at the centre
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# plot the function
plt.plot(x,y, 'y', label='y=e^x')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

# show the plot
plt.show()
```

How can I plot $y(x)=4e^{\frac{-118300}{x}}$ in $[3000,25000]$ in python with this code?

Comment: Hint: read the documentation on `numpy.linspace` (or its MATLAB cousin, `linspace`).

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks very much for the comment. That helped me. Appreciate it.

Comment: There is also [Scientific Computing SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) for questions about computing rather than mathematics.

Comment: @uhoh You've got a point there. Thank you so much for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line $5$, you can edit the range according to your convenience. Then, in line $8$, simply editing the RHS of the equality to your desired function should suffice to give you the desired result. I hope you know the syntax to typing out the code and all the little details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the range as x = np.linspace(3000,25000,100). But I don't know how to change $e^x$ to $4e^{\frac{-118300}{x}}$ and the syntax too. I was wondering if could you tell me about these changes.

Comment: Are $y = np.exp(-118300/x)$ and $plt.plot(x,4*y, 'y', label='y=e^{-118300/x)}')$ right?

Comment: That is about right except you need to add a $4 * $ at the start of $y$.

Comment: @M.Ramana I just noticed the error regarding parenthesis in the second part. I'd suggest using $()$ and not switching to curly brackets. The corrected part would be 'y = e^(-118300/x)'.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it.